# PhysX with ATI + NVidia cards in same computer

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, amd-radeon, nvidia-quadro, physx

I've researched this a bit, however all the information is from previous years and I'm not sure if it applies now. Basically, I have an ATI 4770 and a NVidia NVS 290 and am wondering if it is possible to run PhysX on the NVidia card while having the ATI card still being the main card. (Both cards work without PhysX in the system, powering a total of 3 displays)

I read somewhere that the 257.15 drivers from NVidia allow you to use an ATI card in the same system. Can anyone confirm/deny this?

Comment: @crasic: Uhm, why would such system be illegal?

Comment: @Tom Wijsman its an off-color joke referencing mixed-race marriages and the conservatism of southern states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the release of the 186 NVidia drivers, you will not be able to do this, but before that, you can run Physx on the NVidia card while using the ATI card for output.

However, [this](http://www.ngohq.com/news/16560-patch-re-enables-physx-when-ati-card-is-present.html) article states that there is a third party patch that lets you re-enable this functionality with newer NVidia drivers. I cannot vouch for its quality or whether or not it works. But it might be of interest to you. Proceed with caution, of course.