# Nvidia GPU for PhysX (main GPU is ATI)

Tags: gpu, amd-radeon, physx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PhysX with ATI + NVidia cards in same computer](https://superuser.com/questions/320234/physx-with-ati-nvidia-cards-in-same-computer)

my main video card is ATI 6850, but I also want hardware PhysX (Borderlands 2 look much better with it enables, just that the CPUs of my PC are not fast enough). Since the original Ageia PPU is no longer supported, I should probably buy a cheap nVidia card and use it just for PhysX (the motherboard has one free PCI-e slot and one free PCI-X slot). The OS is Windows XP.

The questions - would this arrangement (ATI for rendering, nVidia for PhysX) work and which card should I buy? There is only space for a single slot card and I also do not want to overpay. I also do not want to replace my main video card with a nVidia one. Should I buy an older (used or not) card or a new low end one?

The other question (the one of which this is supposedly a duplicate) is relatively old (2011 August, maybe nVidia changed again and now allows ATI cards) and does not answer which card would be best for PhysX - an older one, like 8800GT or a newer, low end one, say GT610.

Comment: [PhysX with ATI + NVidia cards in same computer](http://superuser.com/q/320234)